# DragEvent x MotionEvent android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragment

Olá, gostaria de uma ajuda: preciso inserir no meu apk o efeito de arrastar e jogar um item (imagem, texto, icone) na lixeira, igual a função que já vem configurada no s smarthphones ou mesmo apk como instagram. Para fazer os movimento arrastar de um lado para o outro dar zoom, uso o MotionEvent. Porém nção achei nele como realizar o arrastar pra lixeira, e pesquisando achei vários em DragEvent. Porém não consegui usar os dois juntos. Alguém poderia me ajudar como realizar isto usando MotionEvent, ou usando os dois?